# Grothendieck Riemann Roch involving Higher K ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question

As we know, Grothendieck Riemann Roch only involves $K_{0}$. Is there any work generalizing this formula to (Quillen's Higher K)? If there is, what is the meaning for such kind of formula?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hopefully, someone will give you a detailed answer. Such theorems  have certainly been proved by Gillet, Soulé and others. The article by Tamme in the Beilinson conjectures volume may a good place to start.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MR0624666 (83m:14013) Gillet, Henri Riemann-Roch theorems for higher algebraic K-theory. Adv. in Math. 40 (1981), no. 3, 203–289.

Comment: There is also the much shorter announcement, also by Gillet, available freely at http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.bams/1183547545

Answer (score 8):

There is the recent paper [Algebraic K-theory, $A^1$-homotopy and Riemann-Roch theorems](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2710) by Riou, which gives a different proof of the results by Gillet referenced in the answer by profilesdroxford54.

Abstract:

> In this article, we show that the combination of the constructions done in SGA 6 and the $A^1$-homotopy theory naturally leads to results on higher algebraic K-theory. This applies to the operations on algebraic K-theory, Chern characters and Riemann-Roch theorems.

To give you a rough idea, algebraic K-theory is representable in the stable homotopy category arising from $A^1$-homotopy theory of schemes over a regular scheme. As far as I understand it, Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch is just a shadow of the maps from the spectrum representing algebraic K-theory to the Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum. But the paper above considers more than just stable homotopy.